# Call to a member function on array Error

Tags: php, oop

I get the error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function LogInValidatePassword() on array in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectSouls\log-in.php:34`

but unfortunately I can't find the problem with the code.

On line 34 the method `LogInValidatePassword` of the object `user` gets called. In this method I use `password-verify($password, $hashed)`. I pass the Password from the $_POST and the Hash of the database entry, which got fetched in the array `$fetched`.

```
//log-in.php

$post_userpass = filter_input(INPUT_POST,"user_name",FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);    

$fetched = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
/*Line 34->*/ if($user->LogInValidatePassword($post_userpass,$fetched['user_pass'])){
   $user->LogIn($fetched);
}else{
   $user->ShowErrorResponse();
 }


//user.class.php
public function LogInValidatePassword($password, $hashed){
  if(!password_verify($password ,$hashed)){
    $this->errors[] = "Sie haben ein falsches Passwort eingegeben.";
    return false;
  }else{
    return true;
  }
}
```

Since I'm not using a whole array, but just a single value of it, I don't get where the problem might be.

// I looked through similiar posts but didn't find any relatable solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `$user` variable is no class, its an array

Comment: you need to create an instance of the user class first $user = new User() and then call the functions in it

Comment: @Marvin Fischer You got me good on that one. You have good eyes. Thanks m8.

Comment: @vSugumar Been there, done that. Marvin was right, I accidentally declared $user twice, once as an object an once as an array.